# How to alter Table in Sqlite3 in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

Hi I am working with the Sqlite DB.I'm facing one issue I'm created table successfully now i need to alter my table add column like below.

```
-(void) alterDB{
[self open];

sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"ALTER TABLE chatTabelHistory ADD COLUMN imagePath TEXT"];
const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
char *error;
if (sqlite3_exec(db, [updateSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error)!=SQLITE_OK) {

    NSLog(@"Failed to alter =>%s",error);
}
else{
    NSLog(@"DB Created successfully");
}
[self closeDatabase];


}
```

Above method also working fine but when i uninstall my app and the install it is showing while i 'm try to insert a row I am getting `chatTabelHistory has no column named imagePath` my insert method is like below

```
-(void)insert
       [self alterDB];
    NSString *sqlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@(toid,fromid,msg,timedate,left,messageID,chatStatus,broadCastStreamKey,imagePath) values('%@','%@','%@','%@',%d,'%@','%@','%@','%@')",tableName,userid,friendid,message,timedate,(int)leftright,messageID,chatStatus,broadCastStreamKey,imagePath];

    char *error;
    if (sqlite3_exec(db, [sqlString UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &error)!=SQLITE_OK) {
        [self closeDatabase];
        NSLog(@"Faield to insert chat history %s",error);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"chat history inserted successfully");
    }
    }
```

where i miss please help me.

Comment: And what is the error message?  Why are you using `sqlite_prepare()` and `sqlite3_exec()` on the same query?

Comment: while i'm inserting it is showing `chatTabelHistory has no column named imagePath`

Comment: No, what is the error message in the code you posted?

Comment: please check the upadated question

Comment: I don't see how that works at all. You don't have the database open when attempting the insert.  Also why would you do the `ALTER TABLE` every time you want to insert a row?

Comment: I'm opening my db while inserting.if i'm not `ALTER TABLE` every time then showing table does not have column. please don't mind i'm new to sqite

Comment: Well altering a table is something you do very infrequently, normally when updating from one version of an app to another.  Once it's done then you don't need to do it again.  I think you are out of your depth with this stuff.

Comment: Okay Thaksfor the replay

Comment: @trojanfoe can you please tell me one thing i have table now i want to add two columns to the table.